# Windows 8 app javascript Redirect "immediately"

Tags: javascript, redirect, windows-8

I've got this:

```
try{var conn = new WebSocket('ws://' + sessionStorage.ip + ':5565');}
catch (Exception) {location = "error.html";}
```

I would expect this to redirect me as soon as it reaches `location = "error.html"`

Later on in the script I have:

```
conn.onopen = {blah blah
```

But it crashes with

```
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'onopen' of undefined or null reference
```

So the websocket isn't being created, and while the catch does get the exception, it doesn't redirect immediately, instead continuing on for a bit until the actual redirection.

How do I fix this?

Comment: add a return after the location assignment; it's not going to "pre-empt" the currently running script

Comment: @DominicHopton "Return statement outside of function"

Comment: Oh, this is global code, not a function? Put it in a function, and call that.

Comment: @DominicHopton Turns out I just needed it in the `<head>` rather than the `<body>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I previously had the redirect in the `<body>` tag.

```
<body>
    <script>
        location = "error.html"
    </script>
</body>
```

I should have had it in the `<head>`

```
<head>
    <script>
        location = "error.html"
    </script>
</head>
```